# Represent GameObject as a letter in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i would like to represent GameObjects in my game as letters;

For example, blackPawn would be 'p' and blackKing would be 'k'

Ive tried using a switch case statement with no success, below will be the code for it

Is there other easier methods to achive this?

GameObject blackPawn = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("p");

private void Letters()
{

```
    char letter;

    switch(letter)
    {
        case 'p':
            (fill with anything) = blackPawn;
            break;
    }
```

}

Comment: You coukd try a dictionary.

Comment: Im not sure what you try to achieve, but using a gameobject name for something like this seems weird also are you are using the FindWithTag method, you would most likely need a different method which finds the object by their name. Maybe you could create a component and this component could have a enum for all your types? Then instead of finding all gameobjects with a specific name/tag you could get all gameobjects with your component and check it's enum value.

Comment: @R1PFake the only reason im doing it this way is because im trying to make a chess FEN string. for it i need to make each chess piece (gameObject) to its FEN notation, as said above the FEN notation of a black pawn is 'p'. I dont know what methods to use to make each piece be called by its appropiate notation, so i thought a switch case would work.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. I wouldn't rely on the GameObject names because if you need to make a change later, there's a lot of renaming you'll have to do. 
Create a component script and attach it to the game objects.

I'm not really familiar with the chess FEN string, but from what I can tell, the letter comes from the type of the chess piece and its colour. For the black/white colour, I'd add a field which you can edit in the Inspector, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhJa6.png).
As for the letter, since it doesn't ever need to change, you can have it as a constant directly in the script.

The cleanest way might be to have an abstract class *Piece* and have all the chess pieces inherit from it. A class to define everything the pieces should have in common.

```
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary> The base class for all the chess pieces to inherit from. </summary>
public abstract class Piece : MonoBehaviour
{    
    [SerializeField] protected bool black; // set in the inspector for each piece
    public abstract char Letter { get; }

    /// <summary> Returns the chess FEN notation character representing the piece. </summary>
    public char GetFEN() => (black) ? char.ToLowerInvariant(Letter) : char.ToUpperInvariant(Letter);   
}
```

You could add more variables to the base class, e.g. `[SerializeField] protected Vector2Int coodinates;` to hold its position on the game board.

And then make the relevant classes for the specific pieces.

```
public class Rook : Piece
{    
    public override char Letter { get; } = 'R';        
}
```

Then it's up to you how exactly you want to retrieve the pieces to process them. The most basic way is to call `FindObjectsOfType<Piece>()` from somewhere and then process them.
Although I'd probably create a 'Board' component and add all the pieces **as its children**.

```
public class Board : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<Piece> pieces = new List<Piece>();

    void Start()
    {
        // Initialize the collection of pieces 
        transform.GetComponentsInChildren(pieces);               
    }

    public string GetFEN() 
    {
        foreach (Piece piece in pieces)
        {
            char fen = piece.GetFEN();

            // TODO: Do what you need with the character
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have the collection, you could e.g. get all rooks like this:

```
using System.Linq;

var rooks = pieces.Where(piece => piece.Letter == 'R');
```

I don't know if this approach is necessarily *easier*, but in the long run, it should make your code more manageable.